# Spring boot with feign and hystrix: Can't get request timeouts to work

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix

I'm having problems getting hystrix timeouts to work. I've created an example project to show this here: https://github.com/stianlagstad/spring-boot-timeout-demo.

In `bootstrap.yml` I'm setting a timeout like this:

```
hystrix:
  command:
    default:
      execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds: 60000
      circuitBreaker:
        enabled: true
        sleepWindowInMilliseconds: 300000
      fallback.enabled: false
    # My client
    MyFeignClient#getPost:
      execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds: 1
```

I expect the result of this to be that hystrix commands should timeout after 60 seconds, except for `getPost` in `MyFeignClient` which should timeout after 1 millisecond. I'm not seeing that, though. The `getPost` method returns an answer every time, and I'm pretty sure it takes longer than one millisecond.

I've also tried to set the timeout manually in a test using `ConfigurationManager`, but that doesn't seem to work either: https://github.com/stianlagstad/spring-boot-timeout-demo/blob/master/src/test/java/com/example/TimeoutDemoApplicationTests.java

How can I make the timeouts I'm setting take effect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to fix your properties in two places.

First, add the below property. From dalston release, feign's hystrix support is optional. You already have hystrix on your classpath, so all you need to do is just adding the below property.

```
feign:
  hystrix:
    enabled: true
```

Second, you specified wrong `HystrixCommandKey` for your feign. You need to change your HystrixCommandKey like below.

```
MyFeignClient#getPost():
```

You need parentheses after `#getPost`.